# React query a db on component mount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dexie

For this example I am using React with [Dexie.js](http://dexie.org/). I have a code, zanzibar, that, when run, adds a list of objects from my IndexDB to the page. I have two current things I would like to add to this.

First, there appears to be an issue with finding the ID of my database. For instance, when I run `console.log(amigo.id)` under my peaches function, it returns `undefined`. I also do not see an ID on my indexDB panel.

Second, now that I am able to run this from a click function, I would also like to load my indexDB data via `componentDidMount`. The purpose of this would be to load everything on my indexDB to my page on page load. My `peaches` function is supposed to do this, though I am not quite sure how to follow through.

```
var SisterChristian = React.createClass({
  getInitialState:function(){
    return {
    results:[{id:'', name:'',age:''}]
    }
  },

peaches:function(){
    var datastoring = new Dexie('MySpace');
    datastoring.version(1).stores({
      friends: '++id, name, age'
    });

    datastoring.open().catch(function(err){
      alert('Oh no son:' +err);
    }); 

datastoring.friends.each((amigo)=>{
console.log(amigo.id+", "+amigo.name);

}); 

},  

componentDidMount:function(){
return this.peaches();
},

  zanzibar:function(){
    // don't use document.querySelector(), you should be able to access any of your DOM elements like this
    var resname = this.inputNameEl.value;
    var resage = this.inputAgeEl.value;
    var datastoring = new Dexie('MySpace');
    datastoring.version(1).stores({
      friends: '++id, name, age'
    });

    datastoring.open().catch(function(err){
      alert('Oh no son:' +err);
    });

    var newFriend = {
      name: resname, 
      age: resage
    };

    datastoring.friends.add(newFriend).then((id) => {
      // this is how you update the state of the object with new data
        var newResults = this.state.results.concat([Object.assign({}, newFriend, { id })]);
            this.setState({results: newResults});
    });
  },

  renderResults:function(results) {
    return results.map(result => { // this is how you create DOM elements from an array of objects
      return <li key={result.id}>{result.name}, {result.age}</li>;
    });
  },

  render:function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="inputname" ref={el => this.inputNameEl = el} />
        <input type="text" id="inputage" ref={el => this.inputAgeEl = el} />
        <input type="submit" value="Shipping And Handling" onClick={this.zanzibar}/>
        <ul>{this.renderResults(this.state.results)}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }

});

ReactDOM.render(<SisterChristian/>, document.getElementById('bacon'));
```

Included in JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/jgwhxuam/

Comment: you should check out relay: https://facebook.github.io/relay/.  It fetches all the data you need for each react component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Dexie.js, but I think I managed to get what you are asking for accomplished.

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jgwhxuam/2/

First, I moved this block to the top so that you are not repeating yourself ("DRY").

```
var datastoring = new Dexie('MySpace');
datastoring.version(1).stores({friends: '++id, name, age'});
datastoring.open().catch(function(err){ alert('Oh no son:' +err) });
```

Then, I tweaked your `getInitialState` results to an empty array so that it doesn't render some blank spaces on the dom (with bullets, etc).

Instead of console logging the result in the `peaches` function, I used it to take your stored indexedDB data and input it into the state.  I added a `.then()` to accomplish this.  When the `componentDidMount()` runs, it should render the list as a result.

The `zanzibar` function I just consolidated slightly and use the peaches function to update the state.

The `renderResults` function I moved down into the `render` function. Not necessary, but helped me debug.

If you have any questions, I can revise this answer.  Good luck!

Comment: So as far as I can tell the only missing feature here is the ID assignment. My indexDB doesn't show each item having a unique ID.

Comment: Interesting, double check the code is copied over correctly.  I added the `{result.id}` to the output in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/jgwhxuam/3/ and I am seeing unique ID increment correctly as part of the defined schema in `Version.stores()`.  Perhaps try clearing your indexedDB incase you have some old data that is showing up?